Semantic Issue (Xcode): No member named 'memory_order_relaxed' in 'std::memory_order';
while doing flutter build ios / run flutter application on iphone getting the error as

Semantic Issue (Xcode): No member named 'memory_order_relaxed' in 'std::memory_order'; did you mean 'std::memory_order_relaxed'?
/Users/aswanthr/Downloads/ar_cbt/ios/Pods/leveldb-library/util/env_posix.cc:839:33

Semantic Issue (Xcode): No member named 'memory_order_relaxed' in 'std::memory_order'; did you mean 'std::memory_order_relaxed'?
/Users/aswanthr/Downloads/ar_cbt/ios/Pods/leveldb-library/util/env_posix.cc:856:34
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro Max.
This bug issues comes after downloading emulator 18.1 version today for flutter project

Clean prject
Rebuild
tried to fix bug


This issue is related to firebase leveldb package, wait for the release or install the pod directly from this commit, they are currently fixing it, checkout here https://github.com/firebase/leveldb/commit/dc346ebc29fa755f5193dfc9d0a9f463b42a9d2b

related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79137784/after-updating-xcode-flutter-run-fails-with-memory-order-relaxed-semantic-issue

After updating with new changes https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8082
new error is coming
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: absl::lts_20240116::CHexEscape(absl::lts_20240116::string_view)
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: absl::lts_20240116::FormatTime(absl::lts_20240116::string_view, absl::lts_20240116::Time, absl::lts_20240116::TimeZone)
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: absl::lts_20240116::SimpleAtof(absl::lts_20240116::string_view, float*)

Here is this problem. Wait new version.  https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8082
UPDATE: Have a new version.

After updating with new changes https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8082
new error is coming
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: absl::lts_20240116::CHexEscape(absl::lts_20240116::string_view)

solution for undefined symbol issue https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/13563

CocoaPods leveldb-library Compatibility Issue with Custom Commit
If you’re trying to use a specific commit for the leveldb-library CocoaPods dependency, you may encounter compatibility issues like this:
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "leveldb-library":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    leveldb-library (= 1.22.5, ~> 1.22)

  In Podfile:
    leveldb-library (from `https://github.com/firebase/leveldb.git`, commit `f6272399648046e31749d77e9c548712168afcf1`)

Add Podfile
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'leveldb-library', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/leveldb.git', :commit => 'f6272399648046e31749d77e9c548712168afcf1'
end

This error occurs because the specified commit conflicts with the current locked version (e.g., 1.22.5) in Podfile.lock. Here’s a quick solution:
Update Source Repositories: Run the following command to ensure your source repos are up-to-date:
pod repo update
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update

This should download and integrate the specified commit of leveldb-library. According to the Firebase team, this issue is expected to be resolved with version 1.22.6 in a few days. After this version is released, you should be able to use the latest version without specifying a commit
