After Updating Xcode, flutter run Fails with memory_order_relaxed Semantic Issue in LevelDB
I'm encountering an issue after updating Xcode on my macOS system. Previously, I was able to run my Flutter application on the iOS simulator without any problems. However, after the update, running flutter run results in build failures with semantic issues related to memory_order_relaxed. Here's the detailed error message:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             12,5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           15,4s
Failed to build iOS app
Semantic Issue (Xcode): No member named 'memory_order_relaxed' in 'std::memory_order'; did you mean 'std::memory_order_relaxed'?
/Users/denizozaltay/Projects/Nocket/ios/Pods/leveldb-library/util/env_posix.cc:839:33


Semantic Issue (Xcode): No member named 'memory_order_relaxed' in 'std::memory_order'; did you mean 'std::memory_order_relaxed'?
/Users/denizozaltay/Projects/Nocket/ios/Pods/leveldb-library/util/env_posix.cc:856:34


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.

Environment:
Flutter Version: Flutter 3.24.4
Xcode Version: Xcode 16.1
macOS Version: macOS 15.1
Clean Build: Ran flutter clean and tried rebuilding the project.
Pod Installation: Deleted the Pods folder and Podfile.lock, then ran pod install again.

Exactly the same problem here.  I'll update with a github link if I can find if something has broken somewhere.  I expect it will be temporary so I think I'll switch from MacOS to Android development and try again tomorrow.

@atreeon hey guys, it seems it was something related to leveldb-library used by firebase, you can find more info here https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8082. I'm not sure if you're also using Firebase but the maintainer from react-native-firebase (which is what I'm using) got in touch with people responsible for firebase-ios-sdk and they updated, so maybe there's something already ready for Flutter too

For react native.
The leveldb-library cocoapod version with the fix was just released.
you will want to remove your Podfile.lock and pod install again in order to get the fix
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/8082

Update to leveldb 1.22.6

Until this is fixed, MacOS / iOS projects involving Firebase will error on build:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/13564
There is a workaround:
Add this to your Podfile if you want a workaround, note you may already have a post_install section, so you would just use the inner part(s):
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'abseil'
      Pod::UI.puts "Workaround: Configuring abseil to use c++14 language standard for cocoapods 1.16+ compatibility".yellow
      Pod::UI.puts "            Remove workaround when upstream issue fixed https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/13996".yellow
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD'] = 'c++14'
      end
    end

You will need to run pod install again after adding this, so that it executes and updates the build setting

Personally I'm just avoiding macos / ios for Firebase Flutter development as a similar issue happened last week that completely destroyed productivity.  Build for macos / ios yes, debug and run locally during general development; no.

Try them in order;
flutter clean && flutter pub get

cd ios

pod cache clean --all

sudo rm -r Pods Podfile.lock

pod install --repo-update


I did what you said, but it didn’t work. At first, I thought it worked, but then it gave an error that was too long to send to you from here.

Sorry, but the solution to this problem is to replace the existing version with the current one. So if that doesn't work, you can update all the dependents you are using.
